# Cast as INT, sort by DESC issue

Tags: mysql, sql

```
query = "SELECT highest_score FROM users  
         ORDER BY CAST(highest_score AS UNSIGNED) DESC";
```

I have a table where the `highest_score` column is **VARCHAR**(it should be **INT**) but that's not the question.

The question is why does the query return this:

1. -10
2. 255
3. 241
4. 231
5. 125

> Since I am casting highest score as an **integer** shouldn't -10 be at the
>   bottom of the list?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your query...

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides That is natural to you that you are using MySQL, but not for us (I'm working with both MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server). *It is a good practice to always add the most accurate tags to your question.* This was just a side note for the future.

Comment: thanks a lot, I usually pay attention to the tags I use, this time I missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting **negative** values to `unsigned` causes integer overflow, that's why `-10` considered as the largest value.

Answer (score 3):

You are casting it to `UNSIGNED` which can not store negative values. Cast it to `SIGNED`.

Executing `SELECT CAST('-10' AS UNSIGNED)` reveals the reason: UNSIGNED overflows when you are trying to cast a negative value. The above statement's result is `18446744073709552000` which is high enough to be the first when you are ordering.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT highest_score FROM users  ORDER BY CAST(highest_score AS **SIGNED**) DESC
```